# Microsoft Azure Sql connection is slow while connect from VS 2019 C#

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, visual-studio-2019

Am connecting azure sql from visual studio 2019.

I try to create database from VS. but its showing following error.

```
 Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the 
server is not responding.\r\nCREATE DATABASE operation failed. Internal service error.
```

**MY Code**

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder xconstr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
xconstr.DataSource = "xxxx.database.windows.net";
xconstr.UserID = "xxxxx";
xconstr.Password = "xxxxxx";
xconstr.InitialCatalog = "xx";
xconstr.ConnectTimeout = 360;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(xconstr.ConnectionString);
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CreateDatabase ", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbname", dbname);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: Increase `cmd.CommandTimeout`.

Comment: The error is due to the amount of time it take to perform the query (not time to make connection).  The default timeout for Net library is 30 seconds. Depending on the size of the database, the speed of the server, and the amount of memory on the server will determine the time it takes to perform a query.  As mjwills says you may need to increase the timeout to a larger value.

Comment: Also could ref this link: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/498101/Timeoutplusexpired-plusplusTheplustimeoutplusperio

Comment: Hello @Sathish, haven't heard for you for a long time,  is the error solved now? If it's solved, can you show us any details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @mjwills said, please try increase `cmd.CommandTimeout` value. Set the time in seconds to wait for the command to execute. The default is 30 seconds.

Ref here: [SqlCommand.CommandTimeout Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_CommandTimeout): Gets or sets the wait time (in seconds) before terminating the attempt to execute a command and generating an error.

HTH.